Error while building Android 15 (Project Pixelage) | AVBTool, vbmeta.img
[ 97% 150/154 20s remaining] Target vbmeta image: out/target/product/Spacewar/vb
FAILED: out/target/product/Spacewar/vbmeta.img
/bin/bash -c "(mkdir -p out/target/product/Spacewar/obj/avb_chain_keys ) && (out
/host/linux-x86/bin/avbtool make_vbmeta_image --include_descriptors_from_image o
ut/target/product/Spacewar/boot.img --include_descriptors_from_image out/target/
product/Spacewar/vendor_boot.img --include_descriptors_from_image out/target/pro
duct/Spacewar/vendor.img --include_descriptors_from_image out/target/product/Spa
cewar/odm.img --include_descriptors_from_image out/target/product/Spacewar/dtbo.
img --include_descriptors_from_image  --algorithm SHA256_RSA4096 --key external/
avb/test/data/testkey_rsa4096.pem --padding_size 4096 --output out/target/produc
t/Spacewar/vbmeta.img ) && (rm -rf out/target/product/Spacewar/obj/avb_chain_key
s )"
usage: avbtool make_vbmeta_image [-h] [--output OUTPUT]
                                 [--padding_size NUMBER]
                                 [--algorithm ALGORITHM] [--key KEY]
                                 [--signing_helper APP]
                                 [--signing_helper_with_files APP]
                                 [--public_key_metadata KEY_METADATA]
                                 [--rollback_index ROLLBACK_INDEX]
                                 [--rollback_index_location ROLLBACK_INDEX_LOCAT
ION]
                                 [--append_to_release_string STR]
                                 [--prop KEY:VALUE]
                                 [--prop_from_file KEY:PATH]
                                 [--kernel_cmdline CMDLINE]
                                 [--setup_rootfs_from_kernel IMAGE]
                                 [--include_descriptors_from_image IMAGE]
                                 [--print_required_libavb_version]
                                 [--chain_partition PART_NAME:ROLLBACK_SLOT:KEY_
PATH]
                                 [--chain_partition_do_not_use_ab PART_NAME:ROLL
BACK_SLOT:KEY_PATH]
                                 [--flags FLAGS]
                                 [--set_hashtree_disabled_flag]
avbtool make_vbmeta_image: error: argument --include_descriptors_from_image: exp
ected one argument
22:51:21 ninja failed with: exit status 1
There was 1 action that completed after the action that failed. See verbose.log.
gz for its output.

#### failed to build some targets (02:36 (mm:ss)) ####

I get this error while building this Android ROM: https://github.com/ProjectPixelage
I start the installer normally with mka bacon and everything works until I get this error.
I guess behind the last --include_descriptors_from_image flag there has to be an path to an image. But idk how I can solve this.
(Using Ubuntu 22.0.4)
I expected a finished Android 15 build.
I tried to resync, restart my PC and rebuild from scratch.
